# Getting BootMgr not found errors repeatedly on Windows 7 x64

Tags: windows-7, bootmgr

So here is the basic configuration of the box:

Primary RAID 1 (Mirror, Bootable): 2x 300GB WD SATA drives 
AMD Phenom Quad Core x64 @2.2
Asus M3N78 Pro Board
4GB RAM
Windows 7 Ultimate

Additionally, this box is a Host OS for several CentOS Boxes via VirtualBox.

The box runs like a champ but, for whatever reason, everytime I restart the machine I get a BootMgr not found error when the box tries to boot.  I pop in my Windows DVD, select 'Repair Windows' then 'Fix Start Up Problems' and everything works fine...once. When I restart the box again I have to go back through this process.

Any ideas on what is going on?

Comment: Get it running once, then run `bcdedit -enum` and post what it says. It's probably wrong for some crazy reason.

Answer (score 1):

Alright.  The answer here was pretty simple though a bit unobvious.  The board battery had died so I replaced it, no big deal.  All of the defaults for the BIOS were loaded whatever. Well for whatever reason the BIOS had set the Hard Drive priority of the primary boot partition to 1 and the USB Attached HD to 0 and, since the USB drive stores nothing but backups, it makes sense that a BootMgr wasn't found. Oy.